# How can one override theme.palette.action object in MUI theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The MUI documentation says it only exposes some selected palette colors to override and colors like *action* and *text* etc. are not part of it.

Is there any way one can override it at the theme level?

[image]

I tried overriding them like other palette colors but it isn't helping

Answer (score 0):

The palette contains primary, secondary, error colors and also action object, background color, text color etc. For full list of all attributes https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35713736)